# Including Spring context from an external jar does not find services

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am currently using Spring Boot and annotation-based configuration to manage my spring applications. The project is composed of a registration and an external library of services.

Service is composed of classes annotated with `@Service` and have a `@Reposity` injected into them.

Registration injects the `@Service`.

Project Structure (4 maven projects):

```
xelamitchell (Parent POM)
  +- domain
  +- service (Spring JPA)

registration (separate project with Spring Boot)
```

Registration has a maven dependecy to service.

PersonService:

```
package org.xelamitchell.service.person;

import org.xelamitchell.domain.person.Person;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Manages {@link Person}s.
 * 
 * @author amitchell
 */
public interface PersonService {

    List<Person> list();

    Person get(Long id);

    Boolean exists(Long id);

    Person save(Person person);

    Boolean delete(Long id);

}

package org.xelamitchell.service.person;

import org.xelamitchell.domain.person.Person;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

/**
 *
 * @author amitchell
 */
@Primary
@Service
public class DefaultPersonService implements PersonService {

    private PersonRepository repository;

    protected DefaultPersonService() {}

    @Autowired
    public DefaultPersonService(PersonRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Person> list() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Person get(Long id) {
        return repository.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean exists(Long id) {
        return repository.exists(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Person save(Person person) {
        return repository.save(person);
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean delete(Long id) {

        if(id != null) {
            repository.delete(id);
        }

        return repository.exists(id);
    }

}
```

PersonRepository:

```
package org.xelamitchell.service.person;

import org.xelamitchell.domain.person.Person;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

/**
 *
 * @author amitchell
 */
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

}
```

Service Library configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceContext {
}
```

Application configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.xelamitchell"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
//@Import({WebContext.class, ServiceContext.class})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Spring boot is defined in the POM for Application.

The exception I keep getting is that the `@Repository` classes were not able to be injected into their respective `@Service`:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.xelamitchell.service.person.PersonService org.xelamitchell.registration.PersonController.service; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultPersonService' defined in file [/home/amitchell/Workspace/org/xelamitchell/service/target/classes/org/xelamitchell/service/person/DefaultPersonService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.xelamitchell.service.person.PersonRepository]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.xelamitchell.service.person.PersonRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.xelamitchell.service.person.PersonRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at org.xelamitchell.registration.Application.main(Application.java:26)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.xelamitchell.service.person.PersonService org.xelamitchell.registration.PersonController.service; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultPersonService' defined in file [/home/amitchell/Workspace/org/xelamitchell/service/target/classes/org/xelamitchell/service/person/DefaultPersonService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.xelamitchell.service.person.PersonRepository]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.xelamitchell.service.person.PersonRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.xelamitchell.service.person.PersonRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultPersonService' defined in file [/home/amitchell/Workspace/org/xelamitchell/service/target/classes/org/xelamitchell/service/person/DefaultPersonService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.xelamitchell.service.person.PersonRepository]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.xelamitchell.service.person.PersonRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.xelamitchell.service.person.PersonRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:747)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.xelamitchell.service.person.PersonRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:811)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:739)
    ... 31 common frames omitted

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.xelamitchell.service.person.PersonService org.xelamitchell.registration.PersonController.service; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultPersonService' defined in file [/home/amitchell/Workspace/org/xelamitchell/service/target/classes/org/xelamitchell/service/person/DefaultPersonService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.xelamitchell.service.person.PersonRepository]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.xelamitchell.service.person.PersonRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.xelamitchell.service.person.PersonRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at org.xelamitchell.registration.Application.main(Application.java:26)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.xelamitchell.service.person.PersonService org.xelamitchell.registration.PersonController.service; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultPersonService' defined in file [/home/amitchell/Workspace/org/xelamitchell/service/target/classes/org/xelamitchell/service/person/DefaultPersonService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.xelamitchell.service.person.PersonRepository]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.xelamitchell.service.person.PersonRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.xelamitchell.service.person.PersonRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultPersonService' defined in file [/home/amitchell/Workspace/org/xelamitchell/service/target/classes/org/xelamitchell/service/person/DefaultPersonService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.xelamitchell.service.person.PersonRepository]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.xelamitchell.service.person.PersonRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.xelamitchell.service.person.PersonRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:747)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.xelamitchell.service.person.PersonRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:811)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:739)
    ... 31 more
```

Comment: Please post the whole stacktrace. You are scanning for components twice (your `Application` class already scans everything no need to do that again in the `ServiceContext`).

Comment: Thanks Deinum. Included full stacktrace.

Comment: Does `ServiceContext` do any extra configuration other than enabling (the redundant) component scan?

Comment: Nothing extra at the moment.

Comment: I don't understand why you're using an @Imports, since the component scanning will pick up your Configuration files.

Comment: Removed the redundant component scan in service and the @Import in Application but no dice, same error.

Comment: Can you post what your project structure looks like?

Comment: @geoand Added a small representation of the structure: 4 maven projects separated as Parent POM with two modules and a separate project which depends on the service module.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share the code for the below classes? I think that it is related to your service and repository class. You can remove the business logic if you want.

   "org.xelamitchell.service.person.PersonRepository"
   "org.xelamitchell.service.person.DefaultPersonService"

Comment: @ripudam Service and Repository added. This is the actual code at the moment.

Comment: Would you mind adding the packages to relevant code as well? Thanks

Comment: As you are using Spring Boot you do have Spring Data JPA on your classpath as well as a JPA provider like Hibernate?

Comment: `PersonReporitory` does not to be annotated with `@Repository` although that's not causing the problem

Comment: What package is `Application` under?

Comment: @Deinum Yes, I added spring data and hibernate provider in the classpath

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edited after the discussion...

Add the "@EnableJpaRepositories" and "@EntityScan" on top of your Application class.

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("org.xelamitchell")
@EntityScan("org.xelamitchell")
```

HTH...

Comment: I think I found the solution. You need to remove the "@Repository" annotation from the "PersonRepository" as its extending the "JpaRepository" which signifies that it is a "Repository".

Comment: Only PersonRepository is a Repository needed to persist Person. Registration has the datasource for the database. I will be putting up the actual project on Github when I get home.

Comment: Did you try by removing the "@Repository" annotation from the "PersonRepository" interface?

Comment: It doesn't matter if `@Repository` is there or not it doesn't add anything (unless maybe extra clarity that it is a repository).

Comment: The "@EnableJpaRepositories" was indeed missing in the Application class. Deinum is correct though that "@Repository" is unimportant here and also whether I am autowiring the bean to the property or the constructor is irrelevant. Project committed to github.com/xelamitchell/platform

Comment: @ripudam I had to also add "@EntityScan" to find the entities in the domain package. Please edit your answer to remove the autowiring and the "@Repository" removal and add "@EnableJpaRepositories" and "@EntityScan" and I will accept this as the correct answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Where's your implementation of interface: PersonRepository? find it, add `@Repository` on it, and remove this anotation from PersonRepository interface.

Comment: Spring data takes care of providing an implementation of an interface which extends JpaRepository.